# ImageMagick on Rails saying “Image has an extension that does not match its contents”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, paperclip

I recently deployed my first Rails app onto Heroku and configured it to upload images (via Paperclip) to AWS S3 but I keep getting rejected with this error message

```
"Image has an extension that does not match its contents"
```

I think this is about everything I've added since changing my 100% working development app

*models/single.rb*

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { 
        :thumb => ["200x200"], 
        :medium => ["600x600>"], 
        :large => ["1200x1200>"] }, 
        :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

*config/environments/production.rb*

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rmagick'
```

I've tried several images, all of which were exported by me in Photoshop with the correct content type and extension so I do not think the error message is true to the problem.

I just began using Ruby/Rails/AWS/Heroku for the first time this past week so sorry for my lack of knowledge on the subjects

Comment: this any use?  https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1470

Comment: ahh, yes! downgrading worked!! getting an XML error from AWS now but that's probably from screwing with the linkage in my attempts to fix this.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, 
  :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

To:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, 
  content_type: /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)/
```